# How to access XSSAPI from custom jsp Java class?

Tags: aem

I am creating a custom tag library using http://www.cqblueprints.com/xwiki/bin/view/Blue+Prints/Writing+A+JSP+Custom+Tag+Library to produce XSS-proof links from my custom components. I have taken this to a tag since I will need to do other bits of work and to avoid writing scriptlets on the JSP files (I have posted the code at the end).

I wanted to use the XSSAPI from my Java class, but looking at the [javadoc for XSSAPI](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/xss/XSSAPI.html) I see that it's an interface; when using it in a JSP file it's an object that is initialized invoking `<cq:defineObjects/>`.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? There is a method in the XSSAPI class called `getRequestSpecificAPI(slingRequest)` but it's not static, and I have run out of ideas right now.

```java
@JspTag
public class FixInternalLinkTag extends CqSimpleTagSupport {

    private String pathToPage;

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {    

        XSSAPI xssAPI; // ToDo how to get a reference to this?
        urlPointingToPage = xssAPI.getValidHref(urlPointingToPage);

        getJspWriter().write(urlPointingToPage);
    }

    public String getPathToPage() {
        return pathToPage;
    }

    @JspTagAttribute(required = true, rtexprvalue = true)
    public void setPathToPage(String pathToPage) {
        this.pathToPage = pathToPage;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make your tag class an osgi service

```
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = true, description = "User Group Finder")
@Service
public class MyClass { ...
```

you can then use

```
@Reference
XSSAPI xssapi;
```

to pull in the implementation of XSSAPI. Then you can use it

```
xssapi.getRequestSpecificAPI(slingRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm still a bit new to CQ and need to do a lot of reading on services and OSGI!